# How to update context in svelte?

Tags: svelte

getContext and setContext functions can only be called during component initialization. Is there some way to update the context value during runtime, on a click event for instance.
Imagine we store a theme or a localization in a context value and want to create a button to change that. Is it possible somehow?
I've tried set the context using a variable and updating that variable, but it didn't work. Like this:

```
//App.svelte
<script>
    import {setContext} from 'svelte';
    import Name from './components/Name.svelte';
    let name = 'John';
    setContext('name',name);
    function changeName(){
        /// how to update context here ?
        name = 'Mike'; // Doesn't work!!!
        // setContext('name',name);// Doesn't work - Errors
    }
</script>
<Name></Name>
<button on:click={changeName}>Change Name</button>
```

```
//Name.svelte
<script>
    import {getContext} from 'svelte';
    let name = getContext('name');
</script>

<h1> My name is: {name}</h1>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [store](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores):

```html
<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
    import {setContext} from 'svelte';
    import {writable} from 'svelte/store';
    import Name from './components/Name.svelte';

    let name = writable('John');
    setContext('name',name);

    function changeName(){
        $name = 'Mike';
    }
</script>
<Name></Name>
<button on:click={changeName}>Change Name</button>
```

```html
<!-- Name.svelte -->
<script>
    import {getContext} from 'svelte';
    let name = getContext('name');
</script>

<h1> My name is: {$name}</h1>
```

Demo: https://svelte.dev/repl/432d3449cd9b4e5d99a303fa143b3dbc?version=4.2.0

Comment: As I understand, the stores are available everywhere, and context only to the child components, is this a way to limit the availability of a store? What are some other uses of this approach?

Comment: @gajo357: That is a misunderstanding, stores have nothing to do with being "available everywhere". *Anything* directly exported from a module can be imported anywhere. (This is mainly a note to others.)

Comment: In this example I don't get why you wouldn't just pass name to Name component as a prop rather then setting is as context?

What about if you wanted to define user within +layout.svelte so its shared across all components, how would you then change user context within (settings) +page.svelte such that it is reactive to changes to the context?